# OpenGL Variance Shadow Mapping inverted falloff

Tags: opengl, shadows, vsm

I'm trying to implement Variance Shadow Map techniqe with OpenGL API. I have been using tutorial (Fabien Sanglard's Soft shadows with VSM) and followed every step, but my shadowmap looks kind of weird. The main thing i've noticed is that when i change near clipping plane of light (perspective) projection matrix, it starts to look strange.

For example here's how it looks on 1.0f near clipping http://postimg.org/image/rupf6wqcx/ (This result is considered as good)

And here's on 0.1f value http://postimg.org/image/fox04z14z/

Notice that position of the light remains the same.

I've been trying to find what's wrong for 3 days straight with no result.
Can you help me with that?

Here's the code for shadow fragment shader.

```
in vec4 v_position;
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    float depth = v_position.z / v_position.w;
    depth = depth * 0.5 + 0.5;

    float dx = dFdx(depth);
    float dy = dFdy(depth);

    float moment1 = depth;
    float moment2 = depth * depth - 0.25 * (dx * dx + dy * dy);

    color = vec4(moment1, moment2, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And the Shadow Mapping part from actual render pass fragment shader

```
in vec4 ShadowPosition;
out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D shadowMap;
vec4 sc;

float chebyshevUpperBound(float distance)
{
    float p = 0.0;

    // We retrive the two moments previously stored (depth and depth*depth)
    vec2 moments = texture2D(shadowMap, sc.xy).rg;

    // Surface is fully lit. as the current fragment is before the light occluder
    if (distance <= moments.x)
        p = 1.0;

    // The fragment is either in shadow or penumbra. We now use chebyshev's upperBound to check
    // How likely this pixel is to be lit (p_max)
    float variance = moments.y - (moments.x * moments.x);
    variance = max(variance, 0.00001);

    float d = distance - moments.x;
    float p_max = variance / (variance + d*d);

    return max(p, p_max);
}

void main()
{
    /* Shadow Mapping */
    vec3 pixColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    sc = ShadowPosition / ShadowPosition.w;
    sc = sc * 0.5 + 0.5;
    float visibility = chebyshevUpperBound(sc.z);
    outColor = vec4(visibility * pixColor, 1.0);
}
```

Vertex shaders are pretty simple, calculating vertexes from light or camera point of view using MVP matrices so I dont think I need to post them.

This code is for initializing and rendering:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);

glGenTextures(1, &light_s.shadowBO);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, light_s.shadowBO);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor);

glGenTextures(1, &light_s.shadowBOZ);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, light_s.shadowBOZ);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, light_s.shadowBO, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, light_s.shadowBOZ, 0);

while (running)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Shadow pass */
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
        glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(theShadowProgram);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(svxposition);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(spmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, light_s.mProjection);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(svmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, light_s.mView);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(smmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, bunny_s.mModel);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bunny_s.vertexBufferObject);
        glVertexAttribPointer(svxposition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bunny_s.elementBufferObject);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, bunny_s.elementBufferSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbplaneVert);
        glVertexAttribPointer(svxposition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbplaneElem);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(svxposition);

        /* Rendering pass */
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(theProgram);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, light_s.shadowBO);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vxposition);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(normals);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(dpmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, light_s.mProjection);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(dvmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, light_s.mView);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(dbmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, mDepthBias);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(pmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, camera_s.mProjection);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(vmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, camera_s.mView);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(mmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, bunny_s.mModel);

        glUniform3f(campos, camera_s.x, camera_s.y, camera_s.z);
        glUniform3f(lightpos, light_s.x, light_s.y, light_s.z);

        glUniform1i(frsampler, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bunny_s.vertexBufferObject);
        glVertexAttribPointer(vxposition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bunny_s.normalBufferObject);
        glVertexAttribPointer(normals, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bunny_s.elementBufferObject);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, bunny_s.elementBufferSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbplaneVert);
        glVertexAttribPointer(vxposition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbplaneNorm);
        glVertexAttribPointer(normals, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbplaneElem);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(vxposition);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(normals);
    }
}
```

It is not optimized, but will do for now.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to diagnose without code. Can you post some?

Comment: @ChrisMantle I have edited my question with some code samples, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cut your shadowmap storage and memory bandwidth requirements in half if you use `GL_RG32F` instead of `GL_RGBA32F` since `color.zw` (`BA`) is constant. Also, you are aware that `depth * depth` changes very slowly vs. `depth` the closer you get to the near plane with a perspective projection? This leads to precision issues as you can see in your screenshots. Both of these things are briefly discussed in the **Integration** section of [this paper](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/direct3d/Source/VarianceShadowMapping/Doc/VarianceShadowMapping.pdf).

Basically, you need to manage your near and far planes more intelligently (fit it more closely to the min/max distance)... this is good practice for any shadow mapping algorithm, but especially important for VSM.

I would consider throwing out the perspective depth altogether and eliminate the issue of non-linear distribution of precision (you do not need projected depth for the algorithm to work, it will work fine if you compute the regular distance from the light). This ***should*** help tremendously with the primary issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your help! My head was going to explode I was thinking so much to get what's wrong!